# Crafting a block note with draft papers

Tags: paper, book-binding

I have a staple of draft papers. Typically, these are paper sheets that were printing errors in the sense that the print covers less than 10% of the paper.

I would like to reuse them, but I really like to use block notes as drafts for various practical reasons (for example transportability and having my thoughts chronologically attached together). I also like the fact than one can easily take out a sheet from the block if needed.

I don't like the rings (as in the following picture):
[image]

Because 1) the blocks don't pile evenly and 2) approaching the end of the block, I very often encounter troubles to turn the pages (the sheets tend to pop out of some rings, etc.)

**Is there a way to craft a paper block like this one out of paper drafts:**

[image]

<sup>Click on the pictures to get redirected to their source on the web</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a stack of paper and press them together between 2 wooden boards, making sure that one of the short sides sticks out a few mm. 
You then cover the side of the paper that sticks out with bookbinders glue (PVA glue) and let it dry before you unclamp the stack of paper.

You'll end up with a nice noteblock with allows you to pull of sheets of paper out of it but is on the hand strong enough to keep the paper sheets in while flipping through the pages.

I used this when I was a student and used the backside of printed paper from my fathers office.

Comment: There's also something called 'padding compound' which is specifically for tear-off pads.  (I've used padding compound but I've never used bookbinders glue, so I can't say how they compare in strength)

Comment: @Joe: I never heared of padding compound. I'll try it! The bookbinders glue works fine but sometimes, it sticks to good. If you apply to much then it is quite strong.

Comment: it'll make it like the old tear-off notepads that you used to find everywhere (before everyone switched to pads of post-it notes).  You only really see them these days in yellow legal pads & sometimes notepads in hotel rooms.  If you're making lots of small pads, you can stack them all together (cardboard as the lower one), glue, and then cut apart.  (it helps to flex where you want it to break, then slide the knife through from the paper side, so you're well aligned).